# How to handle QueryException for duplicate entries in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, error-handling

Here is my model code trying to handle `duplicate entries`:

```
$userData = ['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password]; 

   public function addUser($userData) {     
        try {
            DB::table('users')->insert($userData);
        } catch (QueryException $e) {
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];          
            if($errorCode == 1062){
                throw ('Duplicate Entry');
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling controller code looks like: `$userModel->addUser($userData);`

Here I am not trying to print any response received from `model`.

**Getting error as:**

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to handle Exceptions correctly and what's the best practise of doing it?

Comment: try to validate information prior to insert it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: that part is quite common, is there a way to handle duplicate exception using catch block?

Comment: yes, there are ways to handle, but i recommend to use validations, if is quite common, split it program that use same function. and for each case make the validation first

Comment: anyway your code is correct except fact of namespace of exception... it should be Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was very near to my answer, it was all about `namespace` issue and error display issue:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e` should be:
  `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e`

```
        try {
            DB::table('users')->insert($userData);  
        } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
            if($errorCode == '1062'){
                dd('Duplicate Entry');
            }
        }
```

`return` and `throw` for error did not work, but 'dd' method worked. So this saves my time in querying twice to identify the duplicates and insert and am happy for it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

```
public function addUser($userData) 
{     
  try {
    DB::table('users')->insert($userData);
  } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
    if($errorCode == 1062){
        return 'Duplicate Entry';
    }
  }
}
```

For more details, please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878719/laravel-catch-eloquent-unique-field-error).

Comment: i saw that post before commenting here, i have the similar code written, how will you return message either by throw or return statement and how to handle it? From controller or model itself?

Comment: @Mithun Let me check it

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to avoid the duplicate entry exception without having to wrap everything between `try{} catch{}`, you could simply use Laravel's `firstOrCreate()` method as follows:

```
User::firstOrCreate([
    'email' => $request->email // unique field here
], $userData);
```

Using this method assumes that you are calling `protected $guarded = []` on your User model.

Answer (score 0):

public function rules() {

```
    return [
                    
        'tool_id' => ['required','integer','unique:assign_toolto_joborders'],
        'joborder_id' => ['required','integer'],
        'assign_date' => ['required','date_format:d-m-Y'],
        'tool_qty' => ['required','integer']
        
    ];
}
```